# Find the equation of a plane normal to the curve (e^t, t, t^2)

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Problem:
Find the equation of a plane normal to the curve $(e^t, t, t^2)$ at the point $t=1$.

Set the curve to $P(t)=(e^t, t, t^2)$,

then taking the derivative twice we get $P''(t)=(e^t, 0, 2)$.

Using $(X-P) \cdot N=0$

If $P''(1) = N$ and $P(1)=P$,

then I get   $ex+2z=e^2+2$.

I'm pretty sure $P\cdot N=0$ should be met, but I'm not exactly sure where I went wrong.

Is this the correct approach? I have realized with a few counterexamples that this derivation may not yield the correct normal. Any insights?

Comment: Why are you taking the derivative twice?

Comment: It is asking for the plane normal to the curve, not tangent. The thinking is the first derivative is tangent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is asking for the plane normal to the curve, not tangent. The thinking is the first derivative is tangent.

Yes, the first derivative is the tangent. And that's what you want! A plane is normal to the curve if it's normal to the curve's tangent vector. In other words, the normal vector to the plane, $N$, is the same thing as the tangent vector to the curve, $p'(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Compute $p'(t)=(e^t,1,2t)\implies p'(1)=(e,1,2)$. This is the normal vector to your plane, which passes through $p(1)=(e,1,1)$. This is enough to determine the equation of our plane,
$$
(e,1,2)\cdot(x-e,y-1,z-1)=0
$$

Comment: Ah. The first derivative, which is tangent to the curve, is the normal vector of the plane which is normal to the curve.

Comment: Yes, exactly. From then you are set